# Hover code in Sublime Text 3 is not responsive nor working

Tags: html, css

I am currently a college student working on a project for a website, been using the Sublime Text 3. I've currently been trying to tackle a specific code in CSS, the :hover, when i was trying to put it in, the code color doesn't change like the others nor does it follow the command when i test it out in the html website. I was hoping if there are any other Sublime Text users who can help me with this problem? Or if possible, if there is an alternative code for this with Sublime Text. Thank you all.

PS: Here are the codes

---

[Here is the screenshot image of the codes in Sublime CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa9ur.png)

---

Comment: Hey, can you share your code as text or SO snippet and not as image?

Answer (score 0):

remove the space betweeen `.navbar-icon:` and `hover`.

```css
.navbar-item:hover {
    background:gold;
  cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navbar-item">element 1</li>
  <li class="navbar-item">element 2</li>
  <li class="navbar-item">element 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you means but remove the white space between your `:` and `hover`. It is a pseudo class `:hover` like others `:focus, :active`that need to be right next to the `:`

In Sublime Text, pseudo classes are white, by default.

[image: pseudo-class/pseudo-element notation]

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-item:hover {
   background:gold;
}
```